# defines manually routes using Symfony2

Tags: symfony, crud, symfony-forms, symfony-routing, symfony-console

I've set up my entities, now I want to 
use the doctrine:generate:crud, during this command it asks what route 
prefix I would like. I would expect that this means that the routes 
would automatically be generate, this is not happening. So I need to 
know if it is supposed to generate the routes, or if I'm supposed to 
create them all manually? If it is the case that I need to generate 
them manually is there a route class, to define all the routes for the 
CRUD operations?

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a CRUD with Symfony, it will ask you to choose a configuration format.

By default, it's annotation. If you haven't changed it, then your routes are in the entity controller, as annotation.

In the example below, you can see the `@Route` anotation, which is how to define the URL in anotation.

```
/**
 * Finds and displays a user entity.
 *
 * @Route("/user/{id}", name="user_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 *
 * @param User $user
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function showAction(User $user) {
    $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($user);

    return $this->render('security/show.html.twig', array(
        'security'=>$user,
        'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

In the end, it's not that "It didn't happen", it's simply and most likely that you haven't read some doc, and didn't knew about it... ;)

[Symfony doc: Routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html)

Comment: i changed the configuration format by yml and it works, thank you

Comment: @SaraLqadi I would suggest that you keep anotation... It's easier to manipulate... ;)